# How to return a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am writing an Angular app. I need method getData()  to always return a promise. So if data is retrieved from local storage and it is not null it should be returned as promise without calling $http.get part.

How do I write it?

```
getData() {
      var data = localStoradge.getItem('data');
      if (data == null) {
        return $http.get('url').then(function(response){
          data = response;
          return data
          })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q.when() does the trick [angular $q API doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Also helpful: [$http API doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

```
function getData() {

  var data = localStoradge.getItem('data');
  if (!data) {
    // assigning the promise returned by $http.get to the data variable
    data = $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
      // setting the data to local storage so it will be fetched from there the next time
      // the response body of a $http response is in response.data
      // see $http API doc linked above..
      localStoradge.setItem('data', response.data);
      // returning this will make the promise resolve to the the content of the resource found at 'url'
      return response.data;
    });
  }
  // $q.when always returns a promise. 
  // If data was found in the local storage that data will be wrapped in a promise which will resolve automatically right away. 
  // If the local storage was not there the data variable will be the promise we get from $http and $q.when will return that promise.
  // In both cases your getData method returns a promise which resolves to your data
  return $q.when(data);
}
```

Comment: Best match, thank you!:)

Answer (score 15):

Just return an already resolved promise if the data is already available (using ES6 syntax):

```
function getData() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    if (data == null) {
        return $http.get('url');
    } else {
        // return promise that is already resolved
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    }
}
```

Then, you can consistently use the interface as a promise whether the data was already available or not.

Note: Since all you were doing in your `.then()` handler was just returning the data, you can remove it entirely.

---

Or, using the $q Angular syntax, it would look like this:

```
function getData() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    if (data == null) {
        return $http.get('url');
    } else {
        // return promise that is already resolved
        return $q.resolve(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to inject `$q`

```
function getData() {
  var data = localStoradge.getItem('data');
    if (data == null) {
      return $http.get('url')
    } else {
      return $q.resolve(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's issue at all as this doesn't return anything if the data is already available in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Use $q to handle promises in Angular:

```
function getData() {
    let data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    let deferred = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http
            .get(data)
            .success(deferred.resolve)
            .error(deferred.reject);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: This `getData()` function doesn't do even close to the same thing as the OP's function.